# C# Autoupdater.net can't extract

Tags: c#

I have a problem with Autoupdater.Net for C#.
My program starts from C:\Systeminventory and finds an update. The program is downloading it and closes the application. All fine. But when installing the update the updater hangs by extracting. Nothing happens.

If I move the application files to `C:\Systeminventory\folder` and start it, the updater download the update and extract it to `C:\Systeminventory`. That's not what I want. I want to start the app from `C:\Systeminventory` and want the updated files into `C:\Systeminventory`. It seems that the updater can't override the old files, but why?

The app is closed and not running. I checked this in the Task Manager. I tested it on my private pc and I'm admin. What did I do wrong?

Using

- Windows 10 21H1
- Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition
- [Autoupdater.NET.Official 1.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autoupdater.NET.Official/)
- .NET Framework 4.8

This is the XML-File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
    <version>1.1.0.0</version>
    <url>https://example.com/update/update.zip</url>
    <changelog></changelog>
    <checksum algorithm="MD5">e2b0bf57f72f865209caab60eb6c13b6</checksum>
    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
</item>
```

This is the code in C#

```cs
try
{
    AutoUpdater.Start(updatePath);
    AutoUpdater.ShowSkipButton = false;
    AutoUpdater.ShowRemindLaterButton = false;
    AutoUpdater.Mandatory = true;
    //AutoUpdater.UpdateMode = Mode.Forced;
    AutoUpdater.RunUpdateAsAdmin = false;
    var currentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    if (currentDirectory.Parent != null)
    {
        AutoUpdater.InstallationPath = currentDirectory.Parent.FullName;
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There's a problem in update");
}
```

Comment: You're not going to be allowed to overwrite a binary that is currently running. If you had an installer, it would unpack into a temp directory and set a flag to cause your bits to be updated as soon as they are no longer being used, but you're doing it the old fashioned way with a zip file.  See https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET#specify-where-to-extract-zip-file-containing-updated-files

Comment: Thanks for this notice. But could you please tell me, how to do that? The snippset on the linked page is in my code. The background is, that I want to do the update with user permissions and as simple as possible. I think clicking the Update-Button and the rest is happens by itself is a nice way for all.

I also can't understand, why the update isn't working. The systeminventory.exe (my app) is closed and not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

I packed the files they are stored in the Debug / Release-Folder to a zip-file
If you do this, you have to remove the "Parent". So the correkt Code is:

```
AutoUpdater.InstallationPath = currentDirectory.FullName;
```

Now it overrides the files and start the new version. All is fine.